# Sending file between systems A->B->C without storing whole file in B

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have 3 separate spring web applications

- **A** uses spring 4.x
- **B** uses spring 3.2.0
- **C** uses spring 4.x

**B** and **C** exposes REST controllers for uploading files

- **A** reads file and uploads it to **B**
- **B** sends the request to **C** without any need to read file content
- and then **C** does whatever it wants with the file.

So the flow would be **A->B->C**

My question is - is it possible to setup **B** in such a way so that **B** wouldn't store whole file in the memory, but would read incoming stream and forward it to **C**?

What I managed to do is:
**A**

```
public void sendFileFromA() throws FileNotFoundException {
    final InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("someFile"));
    final RequestCallback requestCallback = new RequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doWithRequest(final ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            request.getHeaders().add("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
            IOUtils.copy(fis, request.getBody());
        }
    };
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    final HttpMessageConverterExtractor<String> responseExtractor = new HttpMessageConverterExtractor<>(
            String.class, restTemplate.getMessageConverters());
    restTemplate.execute("http://b_url/upload", HttpMethod.POST, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
}
```

**B**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    final ServletInputStream input = request.getInputStream();

    final RequestCallback requestCallback = new RequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doWithRequest(final ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            request.getHeaders().add("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
            try (OutputStream body = request.getBody()) {
                IOUtils.copy(input, body);
            }
        }
    };
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    final HttpMessageConverterExtractor<String> responseExtractor = new HttpMessageConverterExtractor<>(
            String.class, restTemplate.getMessageConverters());
    restTemplate.execute("http://c_url/upload", HttpMethod.POST, requestCallback, responseExtractor);

    return "success";
}
```

**C**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    ServletInputStream input = request.getInputStream();

    try (BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("zibiTest"))) {
        IOUtils.copy(input, output);
    }
    return "success";
}
```

I can easily copy files over >10GB from A to C using B.

With such a solution we can try to stop A while transferring, B and C should be notified about the error, but sometimes it happens that the error message doesn't reach C - it gets closed with socket timeout exception, any idea why this happens and how to implement it properly?

Is this a valid approach or can it be handled better?

Comment: In order to read a file you need to load to memory. Whe you receive the file in B the file is already in memory.

Comment: Write the file to a pipe in one thread in B, then read it in another (also in B) before sending it to C. See java.nio.channels.Pipe . C might want to know how much data it is about to receive (http header).

Comment: @reos well, one can read part of the file, do something with it, then read the next part, ...

Comment: Yes, you can. But in this case you're sending the whole file as part of the request. So when it reaches B it would be the whole file.

Comment: @reos the request object provides the data in an `InputStream` and not a byte array. There is a reason for that.

Comment: You might find it easier to implement this using basic networking infrastructure like a reverse proxy. That way you don't end up re-inventing one in your app server which probably has better things to do.

Comment: @pvg there is some more business logic going on on B - copying the file is just the problematic part - I will read about the reverse proxy

Comment: When you stop A, an Exception is thrown on B somewhere inside the requestCallback, right? Wouldn't that automatically clean up the B->C connection? Or is the (old) spring RestTemplate messing it up?

Comment: I don't understand. In your question you say: _B sends the request to C without any need to read file content_, but then you ask: _is it possible to setup B in such a way so that B [...] would -->read<-- incoming stream and forward it to C?_, which is quite contradictory :/

Answer (score 6):

I would try setting smaller socket timeout on C than you have on B. Currently it seems that both have some default value, so if A hangs, both B and C will stop getting data almost the same time. Both start timing out, and maybe it is a race condition, where it depends on the timeout accuracy which one times out first.

Comment: What's your take on the first (of the two) subquestion? To me it seems B does not store the whole file while in transit, after all he got `ServletInputStream` in B controller and not a byte array for example.